# Make chrome save only some passwords

Tags: google-chrome, password-management

I currently have no passwords saved in Google Chrome (for Windows). I don't like saving any passwords in Chrome for any website with personal information. For this reason, I have made it by default not save any passwords. But there are some websites where I want the password to be saved. Can I keep my default of not saving passwords, but still save certain website's passwords? Is there an extension that will do this?

Thanks,
vikarjramun

Comment: Check http://passwords.google.com is free cloud storage that comes with your Google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, chrome doesn't allow the option of manually adding passwords for sites. If you have it defaulted to not remember passwords then you can't add new passwords (as of now).  As one of the other commenters mentioned, this functionality is included in password managers like lastpass which I use and would recommend as it has multiple other advantages over chrome (like increased security and cross platform).

I guess you could possibly try turning default to remember passwords, go to the site you want it to remember, put in your password and hit remember, then turn 'remember passwords' back to disabled.

If that doesn't work and you don't want to use a different browser ( e.g. firefox dies allow you to add passwords for sites manually). You will have to set it to default "ask me whether to remember passwords" and then for every site you don't want it to remember, select "never remember for this site".

Answer (score 0):

Chrome gives you the option of what to do before saving any passwords.

[Make Chrome remember your passwords](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> #### You can decide if you want Chrome to save website passwords for you, or not.
>
> On some websites, if you save a password to Chrome or Smart Lock for Passwords, you'll be automatically signed in when you visit that website.
>
> 1. On your computer, open Chrome.
> 2. Sign in to a website.
>
>    - To save your password, click Save password.
>    - **If you don’t want to save your password, click Never.**

Comment: I want it to default to not saving the password, unless I specifically set the password myself somewhere

Comment: Try: enable saving passwords, go to a website you want it to save, enter login information, don't select anything, log out. Return to the website and see if Chrome offers to enter credentials.

Comment: Another alternative would be a password manager, such as LastPass.